# How get field value from form builder in Symfony 2.2

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-2.2

How i can get field value from form builder?

My controller:

```
$region = new Region();
$region->setName('TEMP!!');

$formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder(array('region' => $region));

$formBuilder->add('region', new RegionAjaxType);
```

And form type:

```
/**
 * @{inerhitDoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $region = ....
    $builder
       ->add('name', 'text');
}
```

I want get region object from builder form for get variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options have parametr "data"

Example usage:

```
/**
 * @{inerhitDoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $region = $options['data'];
    $builder
       ->add('name', 'text');
}
```

And control usage type with `OptionsResolver`

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver
        ->setDefaults(array(
            'region' => new Region
        ))
        ->addAllowedTypes(array(
            'region' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Region',
        ))
    ;
}
```